# Spring Authorization Server Integration in Keycloak For Authorization Code Flow

Tags: spring, spring-security, authorization, keycloak, spring-authorization-server

I have a requirement where Keycloak needs to be setup as federation with Spring authorization server to authorize and authenticate users.

**Scenario 1:** Using Spring Boot 2.5.4 and Spring Authorization Server 0.2.0 with Keycloak (15.0.2)

1. Using postman,make an Oauth2.0 authorization request,providing client, authorize, token endpoints configured in Keycloak.
2. Client redirected to Keycloak login screen, option to login via the Spring Authorization Server (acting as the secondary OIDC provider) presented.
3. Login screen of the Spring Auth Provider. Enter login. Service successfully authenticates, but fails post callback to keycloak with '999' error code. There seems to be a cached request in Spring Security lib which point to /error and redirectionurl issent as parameter. Defining successurl in the Security config does not solve the problem.

**Scenario 2:** Using Spring Boot 3.1.1 and Spring Authorization Server 1.1.0 with Keycloak (15.0.2)

1. Same test performed using postman. This time, the login through the secondary OIDC provider in Keycloak login page, throws a 400 error. No changes to any other configuration.

Expect keycloak to take the access token form Spring Auth Server, consolidate and return it back to postman.

Can someone please suggest?

Comment: Please don't post the same text multiple times. Tried to remove duplicates, check that everything is still there.

Comment: Please consider upgrading to Spring Authorization Server 0.4.3 (if using Java 8) or 1.1.1 (if using Java 17). Version 0.2.0 is extremely old and not supported. One benefit (among others) with the upgrade will be trace logging via `logging.level.org.springframework.security=trace`. Having said that, I'd recommend checking that your `redirect_uri` to keycloak is correctly configured.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg-I have upgraded the Spring Authorization Server now ,but I still have the error I described for secenario 2.For the redirect_uri ,i've configured the following in the properties 
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/authanz/broker/oidc/endpoint.
Is this the right way or is anything else needed here?

Comment: Please include the trace logs of the request flow in the question so we can help you diagnose further. Please also include your configuration.